# Overriding ASP.NET Membership in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-4

In previous versions of ASP.NET I could modify the Membership Provider settings in web.config to point to my custom implementation.

I'm trying to emulate this in MVC4, but it appears things have changed a little in the template. It appears to be using WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity instead of the classic Membership classes. Do I need to strip all that stuff out and replace it with the Membership calls like I previously did, or is there a way to use the new WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity classes with my custom Membership implementation?

Comment: Why would you use the membership Provider to begin with? Sorry it drives me crazy to see that people are still using this.

Comment: Roll your own man. It is simple... Use OpenId or something

Comment: I would like to roll my own, but I'd like to use the Membership framework to back it.

Comment: OpenID and OAuth are built into MVC 4 applications using the Intranet template. http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/videos/oauth-in-the-default-aspnet-45-templates

I personally would strongly discourage rolling your own membership system for reasons mentioned here: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/05/04/asp-net-mvc-authentication-customizing-authentication-and-authorization-the-right-way.aspx

Comment: @JonGalloway, how would you handle creating the Membership tables in an EF Drop/Create db situation? This is the main reason I want to do this: so the user model integrates better into my rich domain model. (Note: I just browsed that link, so apologize in advance if the answer is in there)...

Comment: @MikeCole I'm not certain - I'm still getting up to speed with SimpleMembership - but I'd start by either implementing WebMatrix.WebData.ExtendedMembershipProvider (rather than MembershipProvider) if you need SimpleMembership account management or doing as Pranav recommends and replacing the new AccountController with an an MVC 3 AccountController.

Comment: How would I plug in the implemented ExtendedMembershipProvider instead of having it use the default implementation?

Comment: Again, you could roll your own and actually spend some time learning how things work

Answer (score 2):

You will have to strip out all the stuff and replace with membership calls if you want to continue using your custom membership implementation.
SimpleMembership(webmatrix.webdata.websecurity) will not work with existing membership implementations